# How to use GoToMeeting in Linux

Tags: debian

My employer wants me and the team of developers to communicate with them using [`gotomeeting.com` service](http://www.gotomeeting.co.uk/fec/). Is it possible to use GoToMeeting in Debian? I know that officially GoToMeeting supports only Mac and Win.

The reason: I am very happy with software development under Linux and don't want to migrate to Windows just because of one or two programs.

Comment: IIRC it worked with Chrome out of the box on a recent Ubuntu. But I'm not completely sure that was GotoMeeting and not one of its competitors, I'll try to check.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the HTML5 version, which runs fine under Chrome, no need to use phone for voice.

Open it at:

https://app.gotomeeting.com

Or if you want to directly open the meeting using the ID:

```
https://app.gotomeeting.com/index.html?meetingid=<id>
```

### Create Shortcut

You can create a Web App in Chrome, clicking in the sandwich icon, then `Install GoToMeeting`.

If this entry is not available, you can use `More Tools` > `Create Shortcut`.

Comment: I just tested this under Chrome on Ubuntu, and after installing their Chrome plugin, screen sharing worked fine.

Comment: @Cerin This is really awesome! Do you mind to post the plugin download page so I can update the answer?

Comment: HTML5 has great amount of issues + they disabled ability to share screen.

Comment: @puchu As I've stated, to share screen you need to install an extension.

Comment: GoTo-Meeting in Chrome uses a lot of resources on many Linux computers I've seen. When it reaches 200% CPU, microphone often stops working. :-/

Comment: Related bug : https://community.logmein.com/t5/GoToMeeting-Discussions/GoToMeeting-kills-my-microphone-on-Chrome/td-p/213059 It seems Chrome 81 solves the problem.

Comment: Seems like the extensions is no more.

Comment: @leandro: the extension was required only for Chrome v71 or older, probably this is the reason why they remove it. I've updated the answer and remove the extension mention, as it's no more required.

Answer (score 11):

There's an option on GoToMeeting setup to permit "Web Viewer". If it's checked you can do the entire meeting within your browser, no plugin or standalone required.
See [the Linux section of the support page](https://web.archive.org/web/20140922083431/http://support.citrixonline.com/en_US/gotomeeting/all_files/GTM130019).

Comment: its worth mentioning that the web viewer do not support voip, so you will have to use the phone for the audio

Comment: Also you dont have Remote access with web viewer

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't work with [Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=7079) or [CodeWeaver](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=1329) (commercial version of Wine), then your only option will be to run a (stripped down) copy of Windows in a virtual  machine (KVM, Xen, virtualbox all support Windows guests) or use an alternative that supports Linux (there are plenty of cross-platform java-based, and opensource ones you can install on your own server).

Comment: Could you please be more precise and name several alternatives?

Comment: I looked at it a few  years ago and had retained DimDim, bigbluebutton and openmeetings IIRC as a short list but didn't go any further for lack of resources.

Comment: But, they are not gotomeeting compatible and will require my employer and a teem to migrate, right?

Comment: Most probably, yes. That's the price for using closed-source and/or proprietary solutions.

Comment: @Shaman, using wine might be perfect for you as would a VM, try those before migrating if it is so important to your employer.

Comment: Google Hangouts lets you do audio/video chat, and screen-share in Linux.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Lack of Linux support correlates with closed-source / proprietry, but it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it on Ubuntu 18.04 and in Chrom{e}{ium}. The image is OK but the sound does not work (I cannot use the laptop speakers/mic). With sound on the phone I can see the shared screens *etc*. but I would call their Linux support pretty poor.

Comment: FWIW the Gotomeeting webapp does not support hosting a meeting or acting as a meeting Organizer.

Comment: This answer was from ages ago, I think in 20 and 22 meetings (as a participant) go OK in those browsers. Never tried hosting one as I'm still trying to avoid GotoMeeting.

Comment: Participating in a meeting is OK in the Gotomeeting and Gotowebinar webapps (in browsers like Chrome). But the webapps do not support hosting a meeting or acting as a meeting Organizer. You need the Windows or Chrome  desktop app for hosting or acting as a meeting Organizer. There is no Linux desktop app.